# Regular expression to parse the string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like this "[[1,2,3,4],sample,test:[abc,acd,12],1000]" i need to split this string to as follows

```
[1,2,3,4] 

sample

test:[abc,acd,12]

1000
```

How to create a regular expression to parse this string.

Comment: I don't understand your pattern. You want to split with `[` and `]`? If so, why `1000` should as a result? And why `nsregularexpression` tag?

Comment: @SonerGönül  thanks for reply , 1000 also inside one square bracket

Comment: _"I need"_ isn't a question. Show what you have tried and what didn't work.

Comment: is the string really contains `[]` at the start and at the end?

Comment: The question is interesting although poorly expressed. The problem is the "recursive" structure of collections denoted by [ and ].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the leading `[` and trailing `]` symbols from the input string and split the resulted string according to the commas which are not present inside the `[]` brackets.

```
string str = "[[1,2,3,4],sample,test:[abc,acd,12],1000]";
string remove = Regex.Replace(str, @"]$|^\[", "");

string[] lines = Regex.Split(remove, @",(?![^\[\]]*\])");

foreach (string line in lines) {
Console.WriteLine(line);
}
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**Output:**

```
[1,2,3,4]
sample
test:[abc,acd,12]
1000
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/DKgSGU)

Answer (score 0):

`[^,]*?\[[\s\S]*?\][^,]*?|[^,]+`